# VirtualBox : 1366x768 resolution

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

My notebook native resolution is 1366x768, however i cant set up virtualbox vms to use that definition.

I cant select from 800x600,1024x768,1280x1024,etc but cant select 1366x768 (native very wide 16" notebook screen)

Seems this is a bug un Virtual Box
http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2047

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install VirtualBox Guest Additions? If you're stuck in a 800x600 resolution this is the solution.

Comment: Assuming your guest supports installation of the Guest Additions you should be able to set any resolution you like, including using "Seamless Mode" which can make the guest OS windows appear as if it is tightly integrated with the host.

Comment: I can select from 800x600, 1024x768,1280x1024,etc
cant select 1366x768