# In VirtualBox can't get max display resolution for guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I'm using VirtualBox with Windows 7 as the guest OS. However the max resolution setting I can get in the control panel is only 1264x602. How can I get up to the full HD resolution that I have in the Windows 7 host?

Comment: Not knowing your setup (host's memory, graphics capabilities, etc.), I can't say for certain, but I can bet it's that you probably haven't allocated enough memory to the VM's video card. You can add up to 128mb, though I would think 32mb would be sufficient. If that works, let me know, and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Other thought: if the guest additions are installed in your VM, then the VM is just scaling to your viewport size. Go to the "Machine" menu, then "Switch to Fullscreen", and that should do it.

Comment: What OS is your VM?

Answer (score 6):

Try to install  VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Comment: Wow you'd think I would have thought of something this obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to allocate more RAM to the virtual video card.

Answer (score 2):

In Virtual Box and Vmware they provide Guest Tools with makes your guest OS to work in normal way and let you communicate with Host hardware.. for example use USB ports from host OS.

First of all check the documentation for your guest OS. that how much memory to split between Host and Guest Os.

After this follow this [link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows) to install tools / Guest Additions on Guest OS.

there are few questions which are similar to your. check this.

[VirtualBox : 1366x768 resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/151104/virtualbox-1366x768-resolution)